# I am getting an error on creating dynamic sitemap.xml using laravel, what am I missing?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, sitemap

Hi am trying to create a dynamic sitemap.xml. I am getting this error;

Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object (View: /Users/guy/Desktop/projects/rentNew/resources/views/sitemap.blade.php)

Here is the code

`

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
      http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

    @foreach ($properties as $property)
        <url>
            <loc>{{ url('/') }}/property/{{ ($property->category->slug) }}-house-for-{{ $property->type }}/{{ \Str::slug($property->location) }}/{{ $property->id }}</loc>
            <lastmod>{{ $date->tz('UTC')->toAtomString() }}</lastmod>
            <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
            <priority>0.8</priority>
        </url>
    @endforeach
</urlset>
```

`

This is the controller

`

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Property;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SitemapController extends Controller
{
    public function index($value='')
    {
        $properties = Property::latest()->get();

        $date = Carbon::now();

        return response()->view('sitemap', [
            'properties' => $properties,
            'date' => $date
        ])->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    }
}
```

`

Hi am trying to create a dynamic sitemap.xml.

Comment: Try checking if $property->category->slug is null before using it.

Comment: `$property->category` is not an object ... if that is the dynamic property for a relationships then that relationship isn't returning a result

Comment: @lagbox Thanks I change it to $properties = Property::latest()->with('category')->get();

Answer (score -1):

Can we see query for $properties.

If you add @php $property = (object) $property; @endphp just below @foreach and it works, your $properties variable is an array, not object

Edit: now that you have added Controller. I think headers might mess with objects and send them as xml

Try passing $view in response()

```
$view = view('sitemap', [
            'properties' => $properties,
            'date' => $date
        ])->render();
```